# Check any special characters in a string in C

Tags: c, string

I tried running this code and it seems that it will only check a character and not a whole string, if I have a long string like "Adam@", does anyone know how to check like the whole string and not just a character like 'n'.

```
    char ch;
    /* Input character from user */
    printf("Enter any character: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    /* Alphabet check */
    if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
    {
        printf("'%c' is alphabet.", ch);
    }
    else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        printf("'%c' is digit.", ch);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("'%c' is special character.", ch);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. -- But at a first glance I would say: your code asks for a char not a string. It reads a char not a string. It checks a char not a string. Why do you ask for a string? If you want to process a string: ask for a string, read a string ("%s") and a char[], and iterate over the array (probably for-loop).

Comment: It may be simpler to use the functions [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) and [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) to determine whether a character is alphabetical and whether it is a digit.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it's OK what he does as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

C language has no direct notion of string. Only the Standard Library has: by convention, a character string is represented as a null terminated character array.

So you must:

1. declare an array large enough the hold the expected strings (say no more than 31 characters)

   ```
    char word[32];   // 31 chars + 1 terminating null
   ```
2. read a (blank or space delimited) word taking care or not overflowing the array:

   ```
    scanf("%31s", word);
   ```
3. loop over the characters of that word:

   ```
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(word); i++) {
        char ch = word[i];
        // copy here your current code processing ch
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

This will only read a single character. To read an entire word, use:

```
char word[32]; // set size to the maximum word length you want to handle (+1 for null termination)
scanf("%31s", word);
```

Then use a loop to check every character in the word, such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    if (char[i] == '\0') break;
    // Check word[i]
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `if (char[i] == 0)`?

Comment: @GauravPathak: That line will cause the loop to break prematurely, if a null terminating character is encountered.

Comment: I think null character is represented as `'\0'`.

Comment: @GauravPathak `'\0'` is equal to `0`

Comment: @GauravPathak: `'\0'` is equivalent to writing `0`. I personally prefer the former, as it demonstrates that it represents a null character. However, as far as the compiler is concerned, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As you would have to use a char array to store this string, you can easily iterate over this array.

Just like htis:

```
char s[100]; //string with max length 100
/* Input string from user */
printf("Enter any string: ");
scanf("%s", &s);
/* Alphabet check */
for(int i = 0; i <100; i++){
    char ch = s[i];
    if(ch == '\0') break; //stop iterating at end of string
     if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
    {
        printf("'%c' is alphabet.", ch);
    }
    else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        printf("'%c' is digit.", ch);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("'%c' is special character.", ch);
    }
}
```